# Set of all non negative integers in the language of rings

Tags: logic, ring-theory, first-order-logic

If the language I am working with is $(\mathbb{Z},+,\cdot,0,1)$, then can the set of non-negative integers be expressed as a definable set? I understand that if I add a binary symbol $\leq$, I have a formula but what about when the binary symbol is not given, i.e. how do I write the formula in this language? Thank you for any suggestions or hints.

Comment: I wonder if there is a more basic definition (not using any theorem from number theory).

Comment: Oh it's a duplicate then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could leverage [Lagrange's four-square Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem):
$$p(x) := \exists a,b,c,d. ~~ x = a \cdot a + b \cdot b + c \cdot c + d \cdot d$$

Comment: Wow great, thank you it never occurred to me even though it is a well-known theorem.